# Using LINQ how do I create a List of one particular field of an entity from a collection entities

Tags: c#, linq, list, lambda

If I have the following collection

```
IEnumerable<ProviderOrganisation> listOfProviders

public class ProviderOrganisation
{
    public virtual string Code { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsDefault { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime EffectiveStartDate { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? EffectiveEndDate { get; set; }
}
```

how do I write the LINQ to produce a collection of just Codes please?

So, just a List of the Codes:

```
List<string> listOfCodes
```

Thanks

Comment: `listOfProviders.Select(x=>x.Code).ToList()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) and [`Enumerable.ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx).

```
List<String> listOfCodes = listOfProviders
                     .Select(p => p.Code)
                     .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call the [`Select()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) method to pull out only the property you need. Then call [`ToList()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) to cast it.

```
listOfProviders.Select(p => p.Code).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

In query syntax, it would look like this:

```
List<string> listOfCodes = (from p in listOfProviders
                            select p.code).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I like using ConvertAll

```
List<string> listOfCodes = listOfProviders
                    .ToList()
                    .ConvertAll(x => x.Code);
```

And a bit of testing reveals that ConvertAll is ever so slightly faster than the current accepted answer's method! :)